# JSF Page fragments & ADF Data Binding

Tags: java, jsf, binding, oracle-adf

Is there any way to use adf bindings in jsf page fragments?

When I create jsf page fragment and layout my components without any binding and when I add this page fragment on my destination page all work well, but when I use adf binding in page fragments it doesn't work.

How can I deal with data binding in fragment within jsf page?

Comment: Your question is unclear. ADF bindings are created by JDeveloper when you drop a data control item into a page fragment.

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide page definition file for this page and register it in Databinding.cpx, you can do it simply right-click in your page fragment and choose "Create page definition".
 
Although jdeveloper will do it for you automatically if you drag&drop anything that require binding on your page fragment.

Answer (score 1):

A JSF page fragment in this use case is no different than a "standard" ADF Faces page. You might find these links useful. Good tutorials and free online training: [here](http://tinyurl.com/advadf-part1), [here](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/11gdemos/insiderBinding1/BindingsPart1.html), and [here](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/11gdemos/adfinsider-binding-internals-2/adfinsider-binding-internals-2.html).